# Linq Select w. Join Statement - Syntax error

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, visual-studio-2010

I have two tables:-

Checkin and Type of Checkin. The key joining the two tables is TypeOfVisitKey.

The values in the 2nd table are fixed and only meant to store definition for visit types.

I am trying to do a linq select + Join, where I can get all the results and create an anonymous type list that I can bind to a Grid (column names generated automatically based on field names in anonymous type).

```
CheckInSystemDataContext objDataContext = new CheckInSystemDataContext();

var checkinList = from c in objDataContext.GetTable<CheckIn>() 
                  join v in objDataContext.GetTable<TypeOfVisit>() 
                       on c.TypeOfVisitKey equals v.TypeOfVisitKey
                  select new { variabl1 = c.column1, variable2 = v.column2};
```

I also tried the alternative way:-

```
 CheckInSystemDataContext ctx = new CheckInSystemDataContext();

 Table<Checkin> chk = ctx.GetTable<Checkin>();
 Table<TypeOfVisit> visit = ctx.GetTable<TypeOfVisit>();

 var chkList = from c in chk
               join v in visit on c.TypeOfVisitKey equals v.TypeOfVisitKey
               select new
                  {
                     TypeOfVisitDesc
                  };
```

However my syntax is not correct... I have done this before but can't seem to get the syntax right.... can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: what exactly is reported as syntax error ?

Comment: on the variable name 'chk' just before the join statement. It says join not found...couldnt find an implementation of the query pattern for source type...

Comment: your chk needs to be an enumerable type

Comment: so I am deriving the definitions straight from the dbml... I don't remember do any special manipulations in the past.... how do I make them enumerable?

Comment: what ORM are you using. IF you use EF, then instead of saying  Table<Checkin> chk = ctx.GetTable<Checkin>(); try to say var chk = dbContext.Checkins,ToList() and similar for visit and it will work.

Comment: Just to emphasize a bit more 
"from c in chk" is the so called "query syntax" while chk.Select(..) is the "method syntax" and they are semantically the same.  Please read this topic as it might shed some light on why you need an enumerable type https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx. To get you started I recommed using the Repository pattern to encapsulate and abstract data access http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem.

Comment: glad that I could help